# Difference between read & execute, file permission

Tags: php, html, web-deployment

This may sound like a pretty basic question, but I'm a bit stumped on what constitutes as "reading" a file, and "executing" a file.

For example: 
User 1 buys a ticket from an online website, and wants to view the ticket (as a jpeg), which is displayed on the website.

Is this considered to be "reading" the folder? or is this actually executing the folder?

If the user permissions is set to "read only," that means the user CAN access the file via an action on the website(in this case, an image of their purchased ticket), but cannot access the file via direct url link right? Such as, www.exampletickets.com/user1/tickets

Comment: Are you talking about the file permissions on disk? Like the ones you set with chmod?

Comment: File permissions are not going to provide authentication/authorization (ACL) that meets the needs as described.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/345833/what-are-perfect-unix-permissions-for-usual-web-project-directories

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Folder Permissions:**

> - Execute -> Actually enter that folder but not be 
>     able to read it's contents, see what files are located there.
> - Read -> Be Able To Read Folder Contents
> - Write -> Edit folders data. delete or create new files/folders inside it and etc

**File Permissions:**

> - Execute -> if it's script like `index.php` run it to get data from it
> - Read -> if it's text file like index.html or `index.php` be able to read it
> - Write -> ability to change its data

As for security, this permissions are only an issue when your server is accessible by other (not from your team) users and this was mainly happening when people where using hosting services where they were not getting dedicated operating system but there was one operating system and all the users where uploading their data there. So if not correctly secured, they could view and edit each others source codes.

Today as usual you get dedicated server, with more security tools and operating system which is accessible only by you and no one else (virtualization).

So you don't need to worry that someone will view or change your data as you are the only one who has access to that server.

Comment: Ah now it makes sense! cheers for your explanation.

One last question:

If the root folder is set as execute only but its child folders are set as read & write, which permission takes over?

Comment: @arsenalftw067 if my answer solved your issue, you can check it as the 'correct' one.
thanks in advance

Comment: @arsenalftw067
if root has execute it will be accessible but not readable or writable
if child has all the permissions that you can read its contents as well as write and execute it.

Comment: I wouldn't use ``index.php`` as an example for the execute permission. It is more the ``php`` binary is executed and the ``index.php`` file is read.

Comment: So, if read permissions were allowed on `index.php` but not execute, the php code (`<?php ?>`) would not run and just be skipped over then?

Answer (score 1):

The webserver (apache, nginx,...) will serve any image files them by reading them, not executing them - same for any other files - regardless if accessed directly or not.

Also, the Linux file permission is given from the machine itself - here, the user will be the user running the webserver instance - usually a linux user named like "www-data". So it does not have anything related to your website's user.

For more information (what are the perfect file and directory permission for your websites ?) -> https://serverfault.com/questions/345833/what-are-perfect-unix-permissions-for-usual-web-project-directories